# The android emulator activate all the sensors I need?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have a problem with an android app. The java files don't have any errors (only some warnings due to variables declared but not used) but when I execute it, in the logcat I have this issue `09-22 09:21:33.310: E/Trace(885): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)` with the Emulator. With my devices *GT-N7100* and *Galaxy note II* I have another error: Pause GC.

But surfing the internet I found on android developers and Samsung developers that probably is a Samsung bug with KNOX, only for my model. I also found that the error I got with the emulator is due because the emulator can't activate sensors I request for the localization services.

If the problem is the sensor not activated by the emulator, can I solve with rooting my smartphone and installing a ROM not based on official ROM but for example on cyanogenmod?

In this link I also paste all the logcat file: http://pastebin.com/y9xsCsfA

Comment: Try using Genymotion which is userfriendly and speed enough for testing

Comment: There no sonsors in the emulator, but you can use sensor simulator : https://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

Comment: @Abdellah even if the emulator don't have sensor (obviously) if I request for them is normal that the app crash when I start it??